# Select random image files from folder JQuery

Tags: jquery, image, html

I have a folder which contains any number of different images in it. I want to select any random image at a time.

```
<div id="putimages">
<img id="my_image" src"any random images from selected folder"/>
</div>
```

How can i do this using `Jquery`?

Comment: server folder or user folder?

Comment: I am using my local folder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your user need to select a directory using browser dialog. Then if directory contains only images, you could try following snippet:

```
$('input').on('change', function () {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        $('#my_image').attr('src', e.target.result);
    }

    if (!this.files.length) return;

    var randIndex = parseInt(Math.random() * this.files.length, 10);
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[randIndex]);

});
```

Relevant HTML:

```
<input type="file" multiple webkitdirectory mozdirectory msdirectory odirectory directory />
<div id="putimages">
    <img id="my_image" />
</div>
```

See for example: http://jsfiddle.net/Dk9rc/

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, if you've for example `100` images in your folder and name your images like `images1.jpg`, `imgaes2.jpg`, `images3.jpg`..... until `images100.jpg`.

Secondly, if you put your images inside a folder called `Images` and your current HTML is the same level as this folder then you can use:

```
var randomNum = Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1);
$('#my_image').attr('src', 'Images/images' + randomNum + '.jpg');
```

Comment: If my folder contains names of the images not like image1.jpg or image2.jpg then what is the way to do

Comment: How do you name it, if it's not follow any naming convention, then it's impossible to achieve your requirement.

Comment: Is it not possible to get all the names of the files in a folder using jquery?