# jQuery – Loading random images from directory

Tags: jquery, html, image, static-site

jQuery noob here, so apologies for the question!

I'm writing up a static site for a client and they've given me a rather interesting challenge I'm not sure how to approach.

They'd like to have a button on a page that takes random images from a directory and places them in a grid. I'm great with the HTML and the styling, I just have no idea where to get started on the jQuery.

This is basically a demo of what I'd like to implement, assuming the button is pressed every second or so.

[image: Random images button]

Is this feasible and/or possible using only jQuery (i.e. having it as a static site)?

*Answers accompanied by explanations are greatly appreciated, as I'm still a learner in web dev!*

Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to get an array of file names pre-known/coded, do the images have any format/name format, or completely random?Do you have any control over the image names?

Comment: @depperm Yes, I know exactly what the file names are and where they're stored. I could call them 1.jgp, 2.jpg and so on.

Comment: @depperm I'm basically trying to implement something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22113400/2188011

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing `$.map()` , `.remove()` , `setTimeout` , `.appendTo()` , `.on()`

```
var updateImages = function updateImages() {
// remove all images from `#container` element having images as child nodes
$("#container img").remove();
// append eight "random" images to `#container`
$.map($.makeArray(Array(8)), function(val, key) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $("<img />", 
      // image files named "image-0.jpg" - "image-7.jpg" ,
      // `key` : `0` - `7`
      {"src": "/path/to/images/image-" + key + ".jpg"})
    .appendTo("#container");
  }, 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 25))
});    
};
// call `updateImages`
$("button").on("click", updateImages);
// set reference to `interval`
// var interval = 0;
// call `updateImages` every `1000` ms
// interval = setInterval(function() {
//  updateImages()
// }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

So assuming you have control over the image file names, I would name them like the example you mentioned, image.png. Your js would look like this (I used a table for styling):

```
$(function(){
    loadRandom();
    $('#clickMe').on('click',function(){
        loadRandom();
    });
});
function loadRandom(){
    var ranNums=[];
    while(ranNums.length<8){
        var t=Math.floor((Math.random()*12)+1);
        if(ranNums.indexOf(t)==-1)
            ranNums.push(t);
    }
    var i=0;
    $('#imageTable > tbody > tr > td > img').each(function(){
        $(this).attr('src','image'+ranNums[i]+'.png');
        i++;
    });
}
```

And the html, again using a table for styling, would look like

```
<input type='button' id='clickMe' value='Click Me' />
<table id='imageTable'>
<tr>
    <td><img src=''></td>
    <td><img src=''></td>
    <td><img src=''></td>
    <td><img src=''></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><img src=''></td>
    <td><img src=''></td>
    <td><img src=''></td>
    <td><img src=''></td>
</tr>
</table>
```